# Populate property from one list by comparing it to another

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Post {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string PostType {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}

    public void SetPostType(Item item)
    {
        if (item.PostId == Id) {
            PostType = item.PostType
        }
    }
}

public class Item {
    public Guid PostId {get;set;}
    public string PostType {get;set;}
}
```

If I have a list of `Posts` and a list of `Items` of different lengths, how can I set the `Posts.PostType` to `Items.PostType` where `Post.Id == Item.PostId`?

Comment: What have you tried so far, where is your code?

Comment: Iterate the `Posts` list, find the matching `Item`, check for null, set the `PostType`.

Comment: I've updated my post with some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Create a dictionary from your List<Item> for O(1) lookup
var dict = items.ToDictionary(x => x.PostId, x => x);

// Iterate over your List<Post> and set PostType
foreach (var post in posts)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(post.Id, out var item))
    {
        item.SetPostType(item);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something if there is no Post with this PostId
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Learned something useful about using dictionary too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

            var joins = from p in posts
                        join i in items on p.Id equals i.PostId
                        select new { post = p, item = i };

            foreach (var j in joins)
            {
                j.post.PostType = j.item.PostType;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Post
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string PostType { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public Guid PostId { get; set; }
        public string PostType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unclear:**

- Are there `Posts` without an `Item`? Are there Posts with an Id that is never a PostId in Items?
- Do `Posts` have at utmost one `Item`? Are there no two `Items` with the same `PostId`
- Does every `Item` with a non-null PostId refer to an existing `Post`?

If a Post may have several Items that refer to this Post, then which PostType do you want to use?

So I assume: every `Post` has zero or one `Item` that refers to this `Post`. If there is no `Item` that refers to this `Post` you don't want to change the value of `Post.PostType`, if there is one `Item` that refers to this `Post,` you want to assign the value of `Item.PostType` to `Post.PostType`.

In this case, you want to find and combine `Posts` and `Items` where `Post.Id` equals `Item.PostId`. You don't care about `Posts` that have no `Items`, nor `Items` that have no `Posts`. In database terms: you want to (inner) Join Posts and Items.

Using LINQ this is done with one of [the overloads of Enumerable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1). You take the two sequences, from one sequence, you take the primary key, from the other sequence you take the foreign key, and when they match you do what is specified in parameter resultSelector:

```
IEnumerable<Post> posts = ...
IEnumerable<Item> items = ...
var joinedItems = posts.Join(itemss,

    // keySelector: try to find matching keys
    post => post.Id,               // from every Post take the Id
    item => item.PostId,           // from every Item take the PostId,

    // parameter resultSelector: 
    // when the keys match, take the post and the item to make one new object:
    (post, item) => new
    {
        Post = post,
        PostType = item.PostType,
    });
```

So now you  have a sequence of all Posts, each with the PostType that was in the Item that referred to this Post. If you have Posts without Items, they are not in the end result. If you have Posts with two items they will both be in the end result.

Update PostType:

```
foreach (var joinedItem in joinedItems)
{
    joinedItem.Post.PostResult = joinedItem.PostType;

    // or:
    joinedItem.SetPostType(joinedItem.PostType);
}
```